# ExtJS -- dynamically change dropdown/picker

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS 6 application. I am using the TagField component with a custom picker which is a grid with a toolbar and some buttons. In some cases, I would like to use a different picker. The picker to be used will be determined by the stores record count.

So if record count is > 50 I want to show picker A, else show picker B.

The issue I am facing is that the picker is created before its store (which makes sense) and once the picker is created it cant be changed AFAIK. And by the time the store loads and I check the record count, its already too late to change the picker.

So is there any way I can destroy the picker and set a new one? I need something like a "setPicker()" method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A more pragmatic solution would be to create two `TagField` components. One using picker A, the other one using picker B. Then you just have to add a listener for the stores `load` event and show/hide the appropriate component based on your condition.

Not so neat, but easy and fast to implement.

Comment: I had thought the same but this wont work for us since the fields are all dynamic and coming from the DB so performance wise we cant have an extra hidden fields there just in case

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use one picker and change it's store to keep things simple. After the picker (combobox) renders you can determine which store to use for it based on the record count of picker A's store

```
        {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Label',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: {
                fn: 'onComboboxAfterRender',
                scope: 'controller'
            }
        }
    }
```

In the controller:

```
    onComboboxAfterRender: function(component, eOpts) {
    var store1 = this.getViewModel().getStore('store1'),
        store2 = this.getViewModel().getStore('store2');

    if(store1.count > 50){
        component.bindStore(store1);
    }else{
        component.bindStore(store2);
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure how this addresses my question but since changing the dropdown is no longer a requirement for us i wont worry about it :) thanks anyways